# Angular 1.5 Components & Form Inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, components

I just started AngularJS and am seeing the modular benefits. Problem is that I I am struggling with forms and components. How do I log my form values? This is extremely basic but I continually get `undefined`.  I'm feeling inadequate lol!

Do I have to create input components? FYI, I bundled my entire form in a component and am only showing one of the inputs.

HTML:

```
<input name="$ctrl.followupId" type="text"  /> <br />

<input type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.logId()">
```

Component:

```
angular.module('followupSearch')
.component('followupSearch', {
    bindings: {
        followupId: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'components/followup/followup-search/followup-search.template.html',
    controller: 'followupSearchCont'
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('followupSearch')
.controller('followupSearchCont', ['followupStore',  function(followupStore) {

    var self = this;

    self.logId = logId;

    function logId() {
        console.log(self.followupId);
    };

}]);
```

Comment: Your `followupSearch` component expects an attribute named `followup-id` to be defined (i.e. `<followup-search followup-id="..."></followup-search>`), the value of which will be used to bi-directionally bind to the model of the text input.

Comment: If you want to bind the value of an input to a variable you can use `ng-model` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel

Comment: miqid - how would I then log the value of the input boxes then?

Comment: rob - Is this the same for when I use components? It doesn't mention that here.

Comment: @PPJN, see this crude example using your snippets http://plnkr.co/edit/KlzHpdyUXV9qgfHOExjt?p=preview

Comment: @miqid - so, in order to use the nhModel and pull form values, I'd need a separate controller? One for the controller, the other for $scope?

Comment: @PPJN, the official documentation provides a pretty good [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form#example) for binding input models to `form` elements. You can avoid two controllers by encapsulating a `form` element within a component, which means you no longer need a controller external to the component to pass in an attribute for model binding (i.e. `followup-id` in your case).

Comment: @miqid - this solved my problem!